# How to get arbitrary TextViews so that I can change their text size

Tags: android

I am making an android app and I want it to have a option in the action bar which allows the user to increase or decrease the text size in the current activity (or the whole app - would like to know how to do both).

I have defined a base activity which specifies the action bar. In the onOptionsItemSelected method I need to be able to get all the TextViews in the activity and change their text size. How would I go about doing this? Also how would I go about making the change persistent across the app?

Comment: It would probably be easiest to have multiple options for the user (small, medium, large).  Then you can simply create separate themes for each option and set your app's theme programmatically based on the selected option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can navigate trough the View hierarchy from the root and get all TextViews.

```
void setAllTextSize(ViewGroup root, int size){
    for(int i = 0; i < root.getChildCount();i++){
        View child = root.getChildAt(i);
        if(child instanceof TextView)
            ((TextView) child).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PT, size);

        if(child instanceof ViewGroup)
            setAllTextSize((ViewGroup) child, size);
    }
}
```

Then you must call this method passing the root of your layout.

Comment: Thank you very much. How do I get the ViewGroup root from the activity though?

Comment: I tink you can getDecorView() and it will contain the layout you inflated. Else you must get with findView